# Send Mongo ID for SQL Server from multiple records

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, tedious

I have a data migrator, which when migrating the data from SQL Server to Mongo, get the generated ID and update the SQL table by inserting the generated ID. The error displayed is "RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state". It seems to me that it is trying to execute the update request without finishing the previous one. (Remember that there are several requests that must be made one at a time)

I've tryied connection.on('doneInProc') event but I did not quite understand how this event works

```
function updateSql(cliente) {
    console.log("ATUALIZANDO SQL...")
    console.log("Entrou")
    request = new Request(`update tbLekkus_Cliente set customerId = '${cliente._id}' where codCliente = ${lastCodCliente}`, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("erro: >>>", err)
        } else {
            console.log("foi")
        }

    })
    connection.execSql(request);
    request.on('doneInProc', function(rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
        return
    });
}

function updateMongo(cliente) {
    if (cliente.action === 'add') {
        db.collection("TesteCollection").insertOne(cliente, { writeConcern: { w: 2, j: true, wtimeout: 10000 } });
        updateSql(cliente)
    } else {
        try {
            let id = cliente._id
            delete cliente._id
            db.collection("TesteCollection").updateOne(id, cliente);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Erro no update aqui', e)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I need to update SQL Server by inserting all generated IDs, one at a time, into all records entered

Comment: You may want to consider changing the update functions to async functions and using await for each DB update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your SQL client library returns a promise from its execSql call, in which case you could achieve what you want using async/await, like so:

```
// NOTE the addition of the async keyword to the function signature
async function updateSql(cliente) {
    console.log("ATUALIZANDO SQL...")
    console.log("Entrou")
    request = new Request(`update tbLekkus_Cliente set customerId = '${cliente._id}' where codCliente = ${lastCodCliente}`, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("erro: >>>", err)
        } else {
            console.log("foi")
        }

    })

    await connection.execSql(request);
    // Won't reach this line until the above has completed

    // Can also be replaced with 'return connection.execSql(request);'
    // but will still require you to resolve updateSql as a promise in the calling function
}
```

Note, however, that this also makes your updateSql function return a promise, so whoever calls it will need to trat it as such by either awaiting it in another async function or by [resolving it as a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).